# Bootstrap Alert Message not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, ajaxform

First - Im not an expert in PHP, but just know how to make some basic changes within contact form using PHP.

On this [contact form](http://christianluneborg.com/clients/scis/index.html#/request) when I filled in the required textfields and hit the submit button it redirects to the contact.php with a `Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!` message instead of displaying the message inside the `<div class="messages"></div>` on request-interpreter.html

HTML (form)

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact.php" role="form">

    <div class="messages"></div> <----- displays alert messages

    <div class="controls">
        <div class="row-form">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="text-req"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-form">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="First name *" required="required" data-error="First name is required." tabindex="1">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email *" required="required" data-error="Your email address is required." tabindex="3">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-form">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name *" required="required" data-error="Last name is required." tabindex="2">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone *" required="required" data-error="Your phone number is required." tabindex="4">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-form">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a message for us *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Your important message is required." tabindex="5"></textarea>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send Request" tabindex="6">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

contact.php

```
<?php
// an email address that will be in the From field of the email.
$from = 'Contact form';

// an email address that will receive the email with the output of the form
$sendTo = $_POST['email'];

// subject of the email
$subject = 'New message from contact form';

// form field names and their translations.
// array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

// message that will be displayed when everything is OK :)
$okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

// If something goes wrong, we will display this message.
$errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

// if you are not debugging and don't need error reporting, turn this off by 
error_reporting(0);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

try
{

if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

$emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    // If the field exists in the $fields array, include it in the email 
    if (isset($fields[$key])) {
        $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
    }
}

// All the neccessary headers for the email.
$headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
    'From: ' . $from,
    'Reply-To: ' . $from,
    'Return-Path: ' . $from,
);

// Send email
mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

$responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
$responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}


// if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

echo $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Alert message AJAX

```
$(function () {

// init the validator
// validator files are included in the download package
// otherwise download from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

$('#contact-form').validator();


// when the form is submitted
$('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

    // if the validator does not prevent form submit
    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        var url = "contact.php";

        // POST values in the background the the script URL
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (data)
            {
                // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                // we recieve the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                var messageText = data.message;

                // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                    // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                    $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox); <------ it should display the alert message, but its not working.
                    // empty the form
                    $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are echoing it (printing it) instead of returning the response, change it like this in your `Contact.php`

```
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
$encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

return $encoded;
}
// else just display the message
else {
return $responseArray['message'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you! After I updated your code. I was able to receive the email, but not the alert message. It redirect to the contact.php page without the message. The alert message still didnt show in the message div.

Comment: Try replacing `if (!e.isDefaultPrevented())` to `if (e.isDefaultPrevented())` why is it set to not, it should check for a truthy value right ?

Comment: I updated and still will not show message in the message div.

Comment: Just do `e.preventDefault();` instead of return false; I guess, check what works, you are preventing the default action leading to your action going to the php page, also check for console errors in the browser

Comment: Remember Im not expert in PHP. What did you mean instead of `return false;`? Because I removed the `!` from `e-preventDefault();` and still didnt work.

Comment: This is not about PHP, this is about your Javascript code. `return false;` will prevent the default action, for some reason you are not being able to prevent the default action. Debug this issue by doing an alert('something') on your submit function, make sure that alert is being displayed instead of your PHP page\]

Comment: Ok, I removed the `return false;` and still same issue.

Comment: Come to chat, let's resolve this issue once and in for all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171100/discussion-between-zuif-and-christian-luneborg).